# Rename Files after merging them, in order to avoid to use them again

Tags: batch-file, rename

I created a Post to [Merge txt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112646/merge-2-text-files-to-one-in-every-subfolder-and-save-them-in-the-same-folder-as) and now I Need to rename the original files (as .txt.ok) in order to avoid to read them again. The Programm is going to be executed every certain time to look for new .txt files to merge an convert to csv, and I want to read txt files just one time.

I have tried with that, but I cant make it work. Probably I am not using the correct Syntaxis.

```
    for /r %%G in (*.txt) do (
    copy %%~pG\*INF*.txt + %%~pG\*RES*.txt %%~pG\"%date% %time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%".csv
    ren %%~pG\*.* >> %%~pG\*.txt.ok
    echo "%%G"
)
pause
```

Could you help me? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? Error messages? Wrong results? ...

Comment: Why don't you just delete or archive the *INF*.txt files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code will fail if it does not find an `INF` file in the directory.  So I am not sure why you wouldn't just use that as the file mask for the `FOR` command.

I am assuming that you have a single `INF` text file and single `RES` text file in each directory.  So why not use some nested `FOR` commands to make sure they are there before trying to create the output file.  If they are both there then the copy will happen and then you can easily rename each individual file.

```
@ECHO off
for /R %%G in (*INF*.txt) do (
    pushd "%%~dpG"
    FOR %%H IN (*RES*.txt) DO (
        copy "%%~G" + "%%~H" "%date% %time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.csv"
        ren "%%~G" "%%~nxG.ok"
        ren "%%~H" "%%~nxH.ok"
    )
    popd
)
```